# How do I use a MailChimp template within Mandrill?

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

Is it possible to use a MailChimp template from within Mandrill?  I linked the two accounts but I don't see my MailChimp templates inside Mandril..?? Any advice or is it just not possible.

I followed this but no cigar.

```
http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21681117-How-do-I-use-Mandrill-if-I-already-have-a-MailChimp-account-
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use MailChimp templates in Mandrill. You'll need to push them from your MailChimp account to Mandrill for them to be accessible. This is a one-time push, so if they're updated in MailChimp and you want the Mandrill version to also be updated, you would push it again.

In MailChimp, go to Dashboard > Templates > My Templates. Hover over a template stored in your account and click Send to Mandrill.

Comment: I dont have this option. I have a paid account.

Comment: @GuilhermeMussi try changing to the "Classic" builder in the Account & Billing -> Settings -> Details menu and then making a new template. "New builder" templates can't be sent to mandrill for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Do refer to this link http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-how-do-i-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content

This will help in merge_tags and their exceptions...it took me quite some time fiddling in order to understand why some of the tags are not appearing in Mandrill